# c++ Pi camera board return black screen

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, video-capture

I am using Raspberry Pi 3 with pi camera board as follow: 
[image]

I want to use opencv(c++) VideoCapture to connect with the camera but it return black screen image. I already enable camera in `rpi-config` and install V4L with the following steps:

Get the source code for the V4L utilities

```
git clone git://git.linuxtv.org/v4l-utils.git
cd v4l-utils
```

Install some packages needed to build V4L

```
sudo apt-get install -y autoconf gettext libtool libjpeg62 libjpeg62-dev
```

Configure and build it.

```
./bootstrap.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Load the module

```
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```

This problem doesn't apprear while using USB camera connected to Pi. Result of running `v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video...` for both video0(pi camera) and video1(usb camera) are:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/workspace/v4l-utils $ v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0
Couldn't open the directory: No such file or directory

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video1 --list-formats-ext
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Index       : 0
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'MJPG' (compressed)
    Name        : Motion-JPEG
        Size: Discrete 1920x1080
            Interval: Stepwise 0.033s - 0.117s with step 0.017s (8.571-30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1280x720
            Interval: Stepwise 0.033s - 0.117s with step 0.017s (8.571-30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1280x960
```

How to properly connect pi camera to opencv?